# Extracting Unstructured data from html table using JSOUP

Tags: java, dom, jsoup, html-table

I have been experimenting using this code using jSoup. The idea is to extract a movie schedule of from this page:

http://www.blitzmegaplex.com/en/schedule_movie.php?id=MOV1970

So far i can only extract the name of the cinema individually. Since it is tagged with a specific class name ("separator2"). while the rest is named as "separator".

I am trying to established the following steps using for loop:
For each ROW in TABLE:

1. GET the cinema title
2. SKIP one row below it (row from step #1).
3. GET the second  with a class named "separator"
4. GET the second  from all  below it (row from step #3). Until it reach the next row which contains a class named "separator2"
5. Repeat the process until all row has been processed.

Could anyone suggest me how should i proceed with this? Or perhaps a better suggestion?

Thanks.

My code so far:

```
public void getMovieSchedule(String movieUrl) throws IOException
{


    //URL url = new URL(movieUrl);
    //Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 3000);

    //Element table = doc.select("table[div=scheduletbl]").first();
    //Iterator<Element> ite = table.select("tr").iterator();
    //ite.next(); // Skip the first row.

    // Actual content
    //print(ite.next().text());

    *** CODE ABOVE DOES NOT WORK ***

    //final String urlSchedule = "http://www.blitzmegaplex.com/en/schedule_movie.php?id=MOV1970";

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(movieUrl).get();
    Elements div = doc.select("div.panelbox");

    for(Element child : div)
    {
        Elements table = child.select("table");
        Elements row = table.select("tr"); // The actual content.

        for (Element a: row)
        {
            Elements cinemaName = a.select("td.separator2");
            print(cinemaName.text().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

HTML to be extracted (some code are omitted):

```
<table width="95%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" id="scheduletbl">
    <tbody>

    <tr>
    <td colspan="3" class="separator2"><strong>BLITZMEGAPLEX - PARIS VAN JAVA, BANDUNG</strong></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><img src="../img/ico_rss_schedule_white.gif" width="16" height="16" hspace="5" align="left"><strong><a href="../rss/schedule.php" class="navlink">RSS- Paris van Java</a></strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="separator">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2" class="separator">TUESDAY, 05 NOVEMBER 2013</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="separator">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="20%" class="separator" rel="2D">
    10:30&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td width="30%" class="separator">
    <a href="https://www.blitzmegaplex.com/olb/seats.php?showdate=2013-11-05&amp;cinema=0100&amp;movie=MOV1970&amp;showtime=10:30&amp;suite=N&amp;movieformat=2D" class="navlink" target="_blank">Buy Tickets</a></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="separator">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="20%" class="separator" rel="2D">
    13:15&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td width="30%" class="separator">
    <a href="https://www.blitzmegaplex.com/olb/seats.php?showdate=2013-11-05&amp;cinema=0100&amp;movie=MOV1970&amp;showtime=13:15&amp;suite=N&amp;movieformat=2D" class="navlink" target="_blank">Buy Tickets</a></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="separator">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="20%" class="separator" rel="2D">
    16:00&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td width="30%" class="separator">
    <a href="https://www.blitzmegaplex.com/olb/seats.php?showdate=2013-11-05&amp;cinema=0100&amp;movie=MOV1970&amp;showtime=16:00&amp;suite=N&amp;movieformat=2D" class="navlink" target="_blank">Buy Tickets</a></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="separator">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="20%" class="separator" rel="2D">
    18:45&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td width="30%" class="separator">
    <a href="https://www.blitzmegaplex.com/olb/seats.php?showdate=2013-11-05&amp;cinema=0100&amp;movie=MOV1970&amp;showtime=18:45&amp;suite=N&amp;movieformat=2D" class="navlink" target="_blank">Buy Tickets</a></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="separator">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="20%" class="separator" rel="2D">
    21:30&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td width="30%" class="separator">
    <a href="https://www.blitzmegaplex.com/olb/seats.php?showdate=2013-11-05&amp;cinema=0100&amp;movie=MOV1970&amp;showtime=21:30&amp;suite=N&amp;movieformat=2D" class="navlink" target="_blank">Buy Tickets</a></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="3" class="separator2"><strong>BLITZMEGAPLEX - GRAND INDONESIA, JAKARTA</strong></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><img src="../img/ico_rss_schedule_white.gif" width="16" height="16" hspace="5" align="left"><strong><a href="../rss/schedule.php" class="navlink">RSS- Grand Indonesia</a></strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="separator">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2" class="separator">TUESDAY, 05 NOVEMBER 2013</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="separator">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="20%" class="separator" rel="2D">
    10:45&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td width="30%" class="separator">
    <a href="https://www.blitzmegaplex.com/olb/seats.php?showdate=2013-11-05&amp;cinema=0200&amp;movie=MOV1970&amp;showtime=10:45&amp;suite=N&amp;movieformat=2D" class="navlink" target="_blank">Buy Tickets</a></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="separator">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="20%" class="separator" rel="2D">
    13:30&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td width="30%" class="separator">
    <a href="https://www.blitzmegaplex.com/olb/seats.php?showdate=2013-11-05&amp;cinema=0200&amp;movie=MOV1970&amp;showtime=13:30&amp;suite=N&amp;movieformat=2D" class="navlink" target="_blank">Buy Tickets</a></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="separator">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="20%" class="separator" rel="2D">
    16:15&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td width="30%" class="separator">
    <a href="https://www.blitzmegaplex.com/olb/seats.php?showdate=2013-11-05&amp;cinema=0200&amp;movie=MOV1970&amp;showtime=16:15&amp;suite=N&amp;movieformat=2D" class="navlink" target="_blank">Buy Tickets</a></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="separator">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="20%" class="separator" rel="2D">
    19:00&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td width="30%" class="separator">
    <a href="https://www.blitzmegaplex.com/olb/seats.php?showdate=2013-11-05&amp;cinema=0200&amp;movie=MOV1970&amp;showtime=19:00&amp;suite=N&amp;movieformat=2D" class="navlink" target="_blank">Buy Tickets</a></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="separator">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="20%" class="separator" rel="2D">
    21:45&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td width="30%" class="separator">
    <a href="https://www.blitzmegaplex.com/olb/seats.php?showdate=2013-11-05&amp;cinema=0200&amp;movie=MOV1970&amp;showtime=21:45&amp;suite=N&amp;movieformat=2D" class="navlink" target="_blank">Buy Tickets</a></td>
    </tr>
    ... MORE <tr> here ...
    </tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you only want to extract some of the details from the table (i.e. cinema name, date, and times), but you are having trouble because most rows have the same className.

So based on that, here's my solution:

```
Elements e = doc.select("table#scheuletbl > tbody > tr > td");
for (Element el : e) {
    if (el.hasClass("separator2")) System.out.println(el.text()); // cinema name
    else if (el.toString().contains("colspan=\"2\"")) System.out.println(el.text()); // date
    else if (el.hasAttr("rel")) System.out.println(el.text()); // times
}
```

Which will print out:

```
BLITZMEGAPLEX - PARIS VAN JAVA, BANDUNG
TUESDAY, 05 NOVEMBER 2013
10:30   
13:15   
16:00   
18:45   
21:30   
BLITZMEGAPLEX - GRAND INDONESIA, JAKARTA
TUESDAY, 05 NOVEMBER 2013
10:45   
13:30   
16:15   
19:00   
21:45
```

Of course, this solution is highly coupled to that particular table on that website, but as long as the format of that doesn't change frequently and is consistent across that website, it will work. You might consider creating a class to store all of this information.